# How to transfrom result printed in a Cmd console to csv file?

Tags: csv, cmd, console, command

This is my command:

```
RefactoringMiner -c  Android-ColorPicker  e2db9453fb8e7585cc4881151c843084cd8fc032
```

It return this result on the console:

```
Move Method   public getId() : int from class com.onegravity.colorpicker.ColorPickerDialog to public getId() : int from class com.onegravity.colorpicker.SetColorPickerListenerEvent
```

I need to transform this result in a csv so I tried to add -reportfile argument but it's not working :

```
RefactoringMiner -c Android-ColorPicker e2db9453fb8e7585cc4881151c843084cd8fc032 -reportfile "C:\Users\AQ42770\Desktop\RefactoringMiner\bin\Android-ColorPicker\res.csv"
```

any help please!